# stuck transaction error: Pre-validation error

Tags: transactions, error, fees, mempool, trezor

[image]

I was trying to send a transaction from my Trezor SimplyStaking wallet over 5 hours ago and seem to get an error.

at the **tzkt explorer**, it says the following errors

Status
Branch refused

Pre-validation error
An operation was rejected due to unknown operation branch.

When I tried re-sending the funds with increased transaction fee, I got the following error:
(Error: Counter 9365347 already used for contract ***my address*** (Expected 9365348))

[image]

is my funds safe? should i just wait? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, your funds are safe. You need to wait a bit and then try again with a higher `fee` or lower `gas_limit`.

---

**Why did that happen?**

You sent a transaction with large `gas_limit: 50000` (despite a simple tz-to-tz transfer consumes about 1427 gas) and rather small, for such gas limit, `fee:10000`. So no one baker picked your transaction to include into a block and then, after ~60min, the transaction became outdated and therefore was rejected with the "wrong branch" error.

**How to fix it**

If you look at [an average transaction](https://tzkt.io/oogL6Gij7abHqBd4Y4RQYAfoD9iPeefUsUVTbbL4NrrnFGbH3sv/3709899)
you will see that the gas limit is 1527 and the fee is 0.000406. So, I suggest you use similar values or at least with a similar proportion, if you want your transaction to be picked by majority of bakers.

If this doesn't help try to use another node, for example [Tezos Giga Node](https://tezos.giganode.io/).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. In Simplestaking wallet though, there doesn't seem to be a parameter for controlling the gas fee/limit. I can only adjust the xtz amount on the transaction fee.

Comment: That's strange... in this case I suggest to contact Simplestaking support team and ask what to do.

Comment: Or, you can try to inject the transaction into the block which will be baked by the [Stake.fish](https://tzkt.io/tz2FCNBrERXtaTtNX6iimR1UJ5JSDxvdHM93) baker (or similar one), because they do not check the fee and pick up all transactions (e.g. even [with zero fee](https://tzkt.io/opRrSvZAnLByrGKms1NCgQzSjUNNf3EhuzC6yDGPNhDdgwtWceV/3882978)).